# Pass a variable from click event to open a specific place in google map embedded

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of several places that I want to show in a Google Maps embedded on my website. When I click on the specific place I want to show it on the map with a marker. For this, I use an `onClick` function that calls a variable.

This is my code:

```
function initMap() {
  function openMap(place) {
    var uluru = {
      lat: 38.697515,
      lng: -9.206199
    };
    if (place == "jeronimos") {
      uluru = {
        lat: 38.734070,
        lng: -8.964710
      };
    }
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: uluru
    });
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}

<div class="title2">Mosteiro dos Jerónimos<a href="#">
  <i onClick="openMap('jeronimos')" class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem with the posted code?

Comment: Does not display the map if I put "if" clauses

Comment: `openMap` doesn't initialize the map.

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: uluru is not defined` (it is local to the `openMap` function).